# How to console selected dropdown option using <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In this code i am not able to console the selected dropdown in console.

HTML

````
<div class="dropdown"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
        <li class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let option of selectedDay">{{option}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>```

TS.

selectedDay = ['GCP','Azure','AWS'];
  selectChangeHandler(event: any) {
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.selectedDay)
 }
````

Answer (score 1):

You can not add change event to ul tag, you need change ul/li tag to select/option tag. And you should distint between selectedDay and listSelectedDay variable.

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
  >
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <select class="dropdown-menu" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
    <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let option of listSelectedDay">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  listSelectedDay = ['GCP', 'Azure', 'AWS'];
  selectedDay = '';
  selectChangeHandler(event: any) {
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.selectedDay);
  }
}
```

Demo code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tapafd

Answer (score 0):

May be You can use button for that code for e.g

----HTML----

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1" name="selected" >
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" *ngFor="let option of Menu">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="selectedChanged(option)">{{option}}</button>
       </a></li>
  </ul>
</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain your code. You can also add a preview with the StackSnippets, instead of using a normal code block to make it easier to see if the code works! Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer